# Angular 5: Returning an Observable from a function

Tags: angular, observable, angular5

In the old days, I would define a new `Promise`, defer it, then resolve it when my function completed.
Now I find myself in a situation where I need to return an `Observable` from a function, and I want to be sure I'm setting it up properly in an `Angular 5` context.

Test function, working fine:

```js
getTreeViewChildren(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true)
                  : Observable<any> 
{

let treeObs: Observable<any>;

treeObs = new Observable(obs => {

 this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().subscribe(data => {
  let hostAccessPoints = JSON.parse(data);
  let accPointTree = this.findChildNodes(currNode, hostAccessPoints, nested);
  obs.next(accPointTree);
  obs.complete(); 
 });  
 
}); 
return treeObs;
}
```

and from my NG component I successfully subscribe:

```js
this.configService.getTreeViewChildren(this.selectedTreeViewItem, type, nodetype, true).subscribe(tree =>{
 let theTree = tree;
 });
```

However the real function has much more retrieval logic. What is the correct way to setup the `Observable` as per my test function above? Same exact pattern, just wrapping all the code within `treeObs = new Observable(..)` ?

```js
getTreeViewChildNodes(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
 let hosts;
 let locations;
 let hostAccessPoints;
 let treeResult: Observable<any>;

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.Location) {  
  // more code..
  let someTree = getStuff();
  return someTree;
 }

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.Host) {
  // more code..
  let someTree = getStuff();
  return someTree;
 }

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.HostAccessPoint) {
  let accPointTree;
  if (sessionStorage["hostAccessPoints"]) {
   // more code..
   let someTree = getStuff();
   return someTree;
  }
  else {
   this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().subscribe(data => {
    // more code..
    let someTree = getStuff();
    return someTree;
   });   
  }
 }

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.HostStorage) {
  // TO DO
 }  
  }
```

**** UPDATED (Based `Observable.of()` suggested answer below):

```js
// Builds hierarchical treeview data
  getTreeViewChildNodes(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
 let hosts;
 let locations;
 let hostAccessPoints;

 
 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.Location) {
  if (sessionStorage["locations"] != null && sessionStorage["locations"] != "undefined") {   
   locations = JSON.parse(  sessionStorage.getItem('locations') );
  }
  // find child nodes
  let locationTree = this.findChildren(currNode, locations, nested);     
  return Observable.of(locationTree);
 }

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.Host) {
  if (sessionStorage["hosts"] != null && sessionStorage["hosts"] != "undefined") {   
   hosts = JSON.parse(  sessionStorage.getItem('hosts') );
  }
  // find child hosts for current node
  let hostTree = this.findChildHosts(currNode, hosts, nested);  
  return Observable.of(hostTree);
 }

 if (nodeTypeEnum === NodeType.HostAccessPoint) {
  let accPointTree;
  if (sessionStorage["hostAccessPoints"]) {
   hostAccessPoints = sessionStorage.getItem("hostAccessPoints");
   accPointTree = this.findChildHostAccessPoints(currNode, hostAccessPoints, nested);   
   return Observable.of(accPointTree);
  }
  else { // **** THREW ERROR FROM CALLER 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined****`
   /*this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().subscribe(data => {
    hostAccessPoints = JSON.parse(data);
    accPointTree = this.findChildHostAccessPoints(currNode, hostAccessPoints, nested);    
    return Observable.of(accPointTree);
   });*/   
                // ** CORRECTED CODE **
                return this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().map(data => {
    hostAccessPoints = JSON.parse(data);
    accPointTree = this.findChildHostAccessPoints(currNode, hostAccessPoints, nested);    
    return accPointTree;
   });      
      
  }
 }
  }
```

and from my component code, it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` only where I call my service which in turn calls http.get():

```
 this.configService.getTreeViewChildNodes(this.selectedTreeViewItem, type, nodetype, true).subscribe(data => {
        this.rebuildNetworkTree(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't gauge enough details about what your second example is trying to return, but a better way of doing your first one would be without the `new Observable(...)` stuff. It would be better to just use the [`map` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) to transform the data.

```js
getTreeViewChildren(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
    return this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().map(data => {
        let hostAccessPoints = JSON.parse(data);
        let accPointTree = this.findChildHostAccessPoints(currNode, hostAccessPoints, nested);

        return 'test123';
    });
}
```

**Update from comment**

If you have a function that sometimes uses an asynchronous operation and sometimes doesn't, you can make use of `Observable.of()` for the non-asynchronous returns:

```js
getTreeViewChildNodes(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true): Observable<any> {
    if (doSynchronousWork) {        
        // more code..
        let someTree = getStuff();
        return Observable.of(someTree);
    }

    if (doAsynchronousWork) {
        return this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().map(data => {
            // more code..
            let someTree = getStuff();
            return someTree;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So `getTreeViewChildNodes()` does not always subscribe to another service; sometimes it just pulls data from `localStorage`, applies some parsing logic, then returns result to the caller. Other times `getTreeViewChildNodes()` may have to subscribe to a service then return the data tree results. So I guess I was trying to apply the Observable pattern (i.e. the way I used to create/defer/resolve the old `Promise`).

Comment: @bob.mazzo I updated the answer based on your comment about the second example in your question.

Comment: I like the `Observable.of()` idea. In fact my component method needs to `subscribe` to `configService.getTreeViewChildNodes()`, so I believe I would need to return `Observable.of()` after each `if` condition. Do I make sense ?

Comment: @bob.mazzo Yeah, every one of your `if` statements where you are returning `someTree` without doing your `this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints()` call can make use of it. `Observable.of(...)` is just creating an observable that emits the single value you pass to it.

Comment: please see my updated post above. I don't want to `.map()` it under `doAsynchronousWork` because I use `data` result as-is . I then pass `data` my data to another function to build the child nodes - then return the resulting tree.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` when `doAsynchronousWork ` is called. Am I canceling out the Observable by calling into my http service to get AccessPoints array?

Comment: @bob.mazzo based on the error you are stating in your updated problem, one of your execution paths in your `getTreeViewChildNodes` method is not returning anything, hence why it is saying you can't call `subscribe` of `undefined`. You'll have to provide your updated code to get some help. Are you missing a `return` before your `this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints()` call?

Comment: @bob.mazzo Ok, just saw your updated code. You are missing that `return`.

Comment: @bob.mazzo You don't need to use `subscribe` there. Change it to use `map` and instead of returning `Observable.of(accPointTree)` simply return `accPointTree`

Comment: I was thinking that `map` would iterate through every value in `data` result. But in fact you are are right. If I `return this.siteConfigService.getHostAccessPoints().map`, then my caller `.subscribe` works fine. I guess in this case I'm returning the `Observable` to my caller; hence, the subscribe() works.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you should use a Subject, somehow like this:

```
let treeSubj = new Subject<any>();
let treeResult = this.treeSubj.asObservable();
// a lot of code
// need to tick a value in treeResult somewhere - can do this in several places
this.treeSubj.next(yourValue)


// and then somewhere need to get that result

this.treeResult.subscribe(tree => doSomething(tree));
```

This way every time you call `treeSubj.next(value)` your `treeResult` subscribers will receive the value.

Comment: in my case, my component method stills needs to explicitly call `getTreeViewChildNodes(currNode: any, nodeType: string, nodeTypeEnum: number = 0, nested: boolean = true)` . In the case of a `Subject`, a subscriber would be waiting for a result. That's where I get confused as to how I would use the `Subject` as you suggested.